# Horizontal line in Algorithmic Environment

Tags: algorithms, rules

I'd like to separate two sections in an `algorithmic` environment with a horizontal line, like:

```
-------------
Algorithm 1: MyAlgorithm
-------------
  Part 1:
  Do some stuff
-------------
  Part 2:
  Other stuff
```

`\hline` causes an error. My code so far looks like:

```
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Caption}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \STATE algorithm here
    %I'd like to do \hline here!
    \STATE part 2 here
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The command `\hline` works only inside tables. To draw a line about the whole width you can use the command `\hrulefill`.

> `\STATE` stems from the [`algorithms` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms), while the more advanced and recent [`algorithmicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) defines `\State`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}


\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Caption}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \State algorithm here
    \\\hrulefill
    \State part 2 here
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

If you want special line formating you can also use every other tool to draw a line. This is the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks, it also works for `algorithm2e`!

Answer (score 13):

Here is a mildly different approach to Marco's answer (which uses `\hrulefill` - a leader). The following MWE defines `\algrule[<thickness>]` that sets a `\hrule` at width `\textwidth` and height `<thickness>` (default is `.4pt`) vertically centered between two lines of code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\algrule}[1][.2pt]{\par\vskip.5\baselineskip\hrule height #1\par\vskip.5\baselineskip}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Caption}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State First part of algorithm here
    \algrule
    \State Second part of algorithm here
    \algrule[5pt]
    \State Third part of algorithm here
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: You can also use `\linegoal` ;-)