# Line number error using "Require" and "Ensure" in package{algorithmicx}

Tags: algorithms, line-numbering, algorithmicx

I’m using the packages `algorithmicx` and `algpseudocode` to write algorithms in my paper. It’s more convenient and beautiful to specify comments than with the `algorithmic`.

But I encounter an error while using “Require and Ensure.” The line's number is always wrong.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
\caption{My first algorithm}
\label{alg:algorithm1}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require~~\\
 If there are multiple lines here, line's number will be wrong.\\
 This error doesn't happen in package\{algorithmic\}
\Ensure~~\\
 If I write $\setminus\setminus$ here, line's number will be wrong too.
\Statex
\If{$i = 1 \to n$} \Comment{This line's number should be 1}
  \State ${\textit{HU}}_{i} \gets {\textit{NGU}}_{i} + {HU}_{i}$ \Comment{Comment}
\EndIf

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Pdf image is here]

### Question

I need to write two lines in item “Require.” How can I tackle this line number problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) maintains the `algorithmic` environment as a list. You could therefore use the `\Statex` command to insert an unnumbered item, similar to inserting an empty line:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{algorithms,algorithmicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \caption{My first algorithm}\label{alg:algorithm1}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require
      \Statex If there are multiple lines here, line's number will be wrong.
      \Statex This error doesn't happen in package \verb|algorithmic|.
    \Ensure
      \Statex If I write \verb|\\| here, line's number will be wrong too.
    \Statex
    \If{$i = 1 \to n$} \Comment{This line's number should be 1}
      \State ${\textit{HU}}_{i} \gets {\textit{NGU}}_{i} + {HU}_{i}$ \Comment{Comment}
    \EndIf
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer is what I'm looking for. Thanks! By the way, how to add a horizontal line before line 1 (i.e., add a split line between Ensure statement and real algorithm)

Comment: @LijieXu: That would be an entirely different question to this one. I suggest asking a [follow-up question](http://goo.gl/vWjuk). Read the linked post carefully.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. While I'm trying to post this new question, I find http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52456/horizontal-line-in-algorithmic-environment has solved this problem.